# It is possible to make the program with md5 hash the change every start?

Tags: c++, winapi, md5

Simple program that can automatically change he's own md5 hash every time you open it ?
There is a programs like 'WinMD5' that scan the md5 hash for program.
My question is if we can change it every time we open the program.
I know that if we add few simple things / or delete some. we can re-co,pile the program and bam we got a new md5 hash.
But if we can do that with just a few lines, and the program will change automatically. it will be great !
any change to do this ?

Comment: The contents of an .exe is immutable in so far as you would destroy it, if you changed a single byte. Besides, why would you do that?

Comment: If you do that your virus scanner is going to get very agitated.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, but not trivially. You will need open the executable file of your program, understand the internal structure of the file ([Portable Executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable), PE), and change something there that won't affect the execution of your program. The ELF binary format (used in Linux) supports all kind of annotations and symbols and extra fields that doesn't directly affects the execution of the program, possibly PE files have them too that you could use. You could also use some static global variable you created in your program specifically for this purpose, since the initial value for this variables are stored in the executable file, on the data segment of the program.

Small changes are enough to change the MD5 hash value completely (MD5 was designed that way). So it would suffice to increment some 4 byte counter in the .exe file every time the program is executed (it would take 2³² executions for the hash to repeat). Use 8 bytes to make it impossible to repeat in mankind existence duration.

As I said, it is not trivial, but not all that difficult or impossible that some may think. Note that the user running the program must have permission to modify the binary executable (maybe Windows will ask for administrative privileges? I don't know, I am not a Windows guy).

Good luck.

Comment: Windows will not pro-actively ask for permission, it doesn't have a crystal ball. And you can't get admin permission once a process has started. "Run As Administrator" means that you do get admin permission for the duration of the process.

Comment: @MSalters Which is, of course, no different than Unix.  Windows has a standard function to find out the full path of the executable.  Unix doesn't (but IIRC, you can find it in one of the files under `/proc/<pid>` under Linux).

Comment: @JamesKanze Fuction that is no more standard than the `/proc/<pid>` way in Linux, since they both are platform specific solutions.

Comment: I just meant that it's not standard Unix.  It will work under Linux, but you'll need something different under Solaris or AIX.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a file or executing it have no effect on its contents.
Under Windows (but not under Unix), it's possible to obtain the
full name of the executable.  If you know places where there are
insignificant bytes, you could open the file and modify them.
(The COFF format has a four byte time stamp, for example, which
you could set to pretty much anything.  Or you could create
a number of useless symbols when you built the program, and
modify their names.)

Of course, this supposes that the user hadn't write protected
the executable file.  I would assume that that's rarely the
case, however, except in a development environment.

Comment: The usual problem with executable files isn't so much write protection (u-w/+R bit) as well as not being root/sysadmin(o-w bit/ACL).

Comment: I consider a file write protected if I don't have the right to write to it.  Even for files that I install, as a normal user, and which belong to me, I write protect executables.  For that matter, even for tools I develop myself, the script which copies them out of the development directories and into where they will be found by `$PATH` write protects them.  (As owner or root, of course, I could change the protection, modify the file, then reset it.)